# How do I run specific RSpec examples across multiple files in RubyMine?

Tags: rubymine

I want to run some RSpec examples, across multiple files, using RubyMine. I'm not trying to run all the examples in those files.

Having run `rspec bisect`, I got an output that looks like this:

```
The minimal reproduction command is:
  rspec './spec/first_spec.rb[1:1:2,1:1:3]' './spec/second_spec.rb[1:3:18]' --seed 4622
```

How do I run these specific tests in RubyMine (e.g. to debug them)?

Comment: I tried many combinations of the options in RubyMine's run configuration but I couldn't get to a configuration that only runs those tests I'm interested in. The most I could get was to run it with the configured seed, but it runs the whole test suite.

Comment: There's a possibility to define a scope of tests to run. Have you tried it?
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/creating-run-debug-configuration-for-tests.html#rspec

Comment: @Olivia Yes, I tried each of the three options but none of them seemed to accept the command in this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Rubymine 2022.3.3, I was able to do the following in my RSpec Run/Debug config:

**Mode**: Multiple Specs

**Specs**: List of spec files delineated with a new line or `||`, like

```
./spec/first_spec.rb
./spec/second_spec.rb
```

**Example names**: List of the actual examples, delineated with `||`

```
./spec/first_spec.rb[1:1:2,1:1:3]||./spec/second_spec.rb[1:3:18]
```

I know this is way late, but I hope this answer will help others who come across this!